# How to use xrandr in order to set multiple monitors scaling correctly

Tags: xrandr

I have Laptop 15" + Monitor 23" and I have no clue on how to fix the scaling. I know I should use `xrandr`.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02 +  60.01*   59.97    59.96    59.93  

  ...
HDMI-2 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  

  ...
```

On the laptop screen the scaling is too small, I cant see barely, and the monitor it seems ok but I think I could scale up and use more space.

Comment: Have you tried using `arandr`? It's a GUI for `xrandr` which saves its settings as a shell script which calls `xrandr`.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa that program doesn't let u change the scale